# Stargazer column on multiple lines *with multiple models*?

Tags: r, latex, stargazer

Similar question as [Getting Stargazer Column labels to print on two or three lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49138023/getting-stargazer-column-labels-to-print-on-two-or-three-lines).

I have long model titles that I would like to print on several lines *while showing the results for **multiple** models*.

Unfortunately, the answer to the other question does not work in this case.

```
var1<-rnorm(100)
var2<-rnorm(100)
df<-data.frame(var1, var2)
mod<-lm(var1~var2)
library(stargazer)
stargazer(mod, mod, column.labels=c('my models\\\\ & need long titles', 
                                    'my models\\\\ & need long titles'))
```

yields

[image]

Obviously, I would like for each title to remain in its column (as if it was included in an \mbox or something).

I've tried several variants of

```
var1<-rnorm(100)
var2<-rnorm(100)
df<-data.frame(var1, var2)
mod<-lm(var1~var2)
library(stargazer)
stargazer(mod, mod, column.labels=c('\\mbox\{my models\\\\ & need long titles\}', 
                                    '\\mbox\{my models\\\\ & need long titles\}'))
```

but I always get errors. I am not quite sure how to properly escape the \mbox command so it's properly read by latex, or whether that would even work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, my apologies, I was really close, I should have looked a little harder before posting. The key was 1) to use `\shortstack` instead of `\mbox` and 2) *not* to escape the `{` characters.

```
var1<-rnorm(100)
var2<-rnorm(100)
df<-data.frame(var1, var2)
mod<-lm(var1~var2)
library(stargazer)
stargazer(mod, mod, column.labels=c('\\shortstack{my models \\\\ need long titles}', 
                                    '\\shortstack{my models \\\\ need long titles}'))
```

[image]